# Confusion on linear combination/dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

The set $\{\sin(t), \cos(t)\}$ is linearly independent in $C[0,1]$ the space of all continuous functions on $0 \leq t \leq 1$, because $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ are not multiples of one another as vectors in $C[0,1]$. Thatis,there is no scalar $c$ such that $\cos(t) = c\sin(t)$ for all $t$ in $C[0,1]$. (Look at the graphs of $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$). However, $\{\sin(t)\cos(t), \sin(2t)\}$ is linearly dependent because of the identity: $\sin(2t) = 2\sin(t)\cos(t) $, for all $t$.

I'm confused on the rationale for why they are linearly dependent. The definition of a linear combination is "is an expression constructed from a set of terms by multiplying each term by a constant and adding the results (e.g. a linear combination of $x$ and $y$ would be any expression of the form $ax + by$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants)". So it seems to me that this is in the form of $axy$.

Comment: Do you recall the identity $2\sin(t) \cos(t) = \sin(2t)$?   Do you see how the left hand side and the right hand side describe the _exact_ same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here $x=\sin(t)\cos(t)$ and $y = \sin(2t).$ You have $$2x-y=0 $$ which is a nontrivial linear combination of the two that equals zero. The definition of linear dependence is that such a combination exists.